# Representing points in 2D and 3D spaces with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need an example for Representing points in 2D and 3D spaces with Prolog

Answer (score 0):

How about terms that look like

```
point(X,Y,Z)
```

where X,Y,Z are numbers (floats, integers, rationals, ...).

Then you can do thinks like:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% move(PointIn,PointOut,Vector)

move(point(X,Y,Z),point(NX,NY,NZ),point(VX,VY,VZ)) :-
   NX #= X + VX,
   NY #= Y + VY,
   NZ #= Z + VZ.
```

Then:

```
?- move(point(1,2,3),New,point(5,5,5)).
New = point(6, 7, 8).
```